# PyLint not recognizing cv2 members

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am running pylint on an opencv project and I am getting many pylint errors in VS code about  members not being present.

Example code:

```
import cv2
cv2.imshow(....)
```

Errors obtained:

[image]

However , the code runs correctly without any errors.

Versions : pylint 1.8.1 , astroid 1.6.0

Answer (score 126, accepted):

This is from pylint. You can generate a pylint config file in the root of your project with this command:
(I find this to be helpful if you work in a team or on different computers from the same repo)

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc
```

At the beginning of the generated .pylintrc file you will see

```
# A comma-separated list of package or module names from where C extensions may
# be loaded. Extensions are loading into the active Python interpreter and may
# run arbitrary code.
extension-pkg-whitelist=
```

Add cv2 so you end up with

```
# A comma-separated list of package or module names from where C extensions may
# be loaded. Extensions are loading into the active Python interpreter and may
# run arbitrary code.
extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2
```

Save the file.
The lint errors should disappear.

Comment: If you installed linter extension, may be the file .pylintrc already exists - and it may be empty.  You only have to add the line extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2 and save.

Comment: Does this simply ignore anything to do with cv2 and is it a good thing to do? `cv2` is not the only module for whom Pylint will throw this error.

Answer (score 45):

1. On VScode: CTRL + Shift + P
2. Choose "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"
3. Add this line into JSON file:
   "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"]

Done, it works for me

Note: Make sure you choose "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)", not "Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)"

Setting File would look like

```
{
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
"kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
"python.dataScience.askForKernelRestart": false,
"python.dataScience.jupyterServerURI": "local",
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
"workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
"vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"] }
```

Comment: There is no option '--generate-members'. I tried this in VS Code, I thought this worked but it turns out pylint actually exits with an error that does not show in VS Code.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm in VSCode 1.55.2.

Comment: Yes, It's working for VS Code version 1.56.2 also on windows 10...

Comment: @Clément is correct: no, this is not working. This is breaking `pylint`, and that is why your lints are disappearing (all of them!). Check yourselves by issueing `pylint --generate-members` or checking VS Code's Output - Python window. I cannot believe this has been upvoted 40+ times.

Comment: `--generate*d*_members` is a valid flag, but takes an argument (`cv2.*`, in this case).

Comment: @bers: What do you recommend doing other than whitelist `cv2`, or whatever module whose members Pylint doesn't recognize?

Comment: @bytrangle I said nothing against whitelisting `cv2`. It's just that this answer does not whitelist `cv2`, but it breaks `pylint`. It's certainly a way to make lints disappear, but probably not the intended one if it removes all of them.

Comment: @bers: I was just interested to know if you had another solution other than whitelisting `cv2`. At the very least, Pylint doesn't recognize the dynamic members of `cv2` and `numpy`.The whitelist may be long.

Comment: @bytrangle no, unfortunately.

Comment: VsCode json style has been changed. As of 2023.09, this should work:
  "pylint.args": [
   "--generate-members"
  ]

Answer (score 35):

Try import cv2 like this:

```py
from cv2 import cv2
```

Comment: It would be good if you described what their problem was/ mistake was and how this solves it.

Comment: This does indeed work -- at least for me -- but _whyyyy_?

Comment: why though?! This is hilarious.

Comment: I won't give you a thumb up until you tell me why it works...

Comment: I love it because this is a simple answer :D however it will be nice if somebody explain why it works :)

Comment: Newer pylint versions (2.10.2) simply change the message from `no-member` to `c-extension-no-member` and suggests adding the module to "extension-pkg-allow-list" as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51916065/1259982)

Comment: This....really works.

Comment: `ImportError: Bindings generation error. Submodule name should always start with a parent module name. Parent name: cv2.cv2. Submodule name: cv2
`

Answer (score 16):

Yes it is because the extension has not been installed. 
Set this: extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2 and you're good to go.
However it may not detect the functions or modules implemented in cv2

[image]

Comment: it would be nice if you also add code snippets, since images are not searchable, nor [copy-paste-able](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/53/be/34/53be34c987b10821f7c10b9d88436b92.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the image, way more helpful than a one line code snippet without context.

Answer (score 14):

Here the code snippet for the settings.json file in MS V Code

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs":["--extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2"]
```

Answer (score 8):

In VSCode, edit the Settings JSON (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`, > "Preferences: Open Settings JSON)

Then, paste the following into the JSON:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    ... // prievious arguments
    "--generated-members=cv2.*"
]
```

Don't know why, but other solutions (allowlist, etc) weren't working for me, and I didn't want ot create the `.pylintrc` file.

Comment: Equivalent to setting `generated-members=cv2.*` in the .pylintrc.

Comment: Seems for latest versions it should be `pylint.args` instead of `python.linting.pylintArgs`

Answer (score 5):

As discussed in this [closed pylint issue](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/2426), `extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2` doesn't always work. Meanwhile, `--generated-members=cv2.*` solves the issue most of the time. Therefore, one can configure [`generated-members`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/v2.17.2/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#generated-members) in the command line as `pylint --generated-members=cv2.*` or put the configuration in the `pyproject.toml` file as

```ini
[tool.pylint.typecheck]
# List of members which are set dynamically and missed by pylint inference
# system, and so shouldn't trigger E1101 when accessed. Python regular
# expressions are accepted.
generated-members = ["cv2.*"]
```

Note, the configuration above can be generated automatically by `pylint --generated-members=cv2.* --generate-toml-config` according to the [official documentation](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have to change anything in the pylint Jason file like the most of the answers here My solution is to change the import statement to the form below

```py
from cv2 import cv2
```

Eventually, cv2 members can be used!

Comment: @SimonLundberg I'm actually tried to find an answer .. but I couldn't .. but still works !

Answer (score 1):

I used below config settings in settings.json of vscode and it helped me avoid the unessential flags by pylint, and also got intellisense for cv2 working,
it it doesn't work try uninstalling and deleting cv2 packages from C:\Anaconda3\envs\demo1\Lib\site-packages folder, and reinstalling opencv-python package

```
{
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2"
  ]
}
```