# E1101:Module 'cv2' has no 'copyMakeBorder' member

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

Help this is my first time coding python and I want to make a program that makes square images by padding the input image. I coded but I don't know why i keep getting these errors:

> E1101:Module 'cv2' has no 'copyMakeBorder' member
>
> E1101:Module 'cv2' has no 'BORDER_CONSTANT' member

I think everything looks alright. here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
from PIL import Image

path = sys.argv

def cropper(path):

im = Image.open(path)
x , y = im.size
area = (0,0,x,y-20)
cropped_im = im.crop(area)

return cropped_im

def resize(Image):
im = Image
x , y = im.size
ratio = x/y
white = [255,255,255]
if ratio>1: #horizontal side is larger#
    vpad = cv2.copyMakeBorder((x-y)/2, (x-y)/2,0,0, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=white)
    return vpad
elif ratio<1: #vertical side is bigger
    hpad = cv2.copyMakeBorder(0,0,(y-x)/2,(y-x)/2, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=white)
    return hpad
else:
    return im
```

I'm using visual studio to code. please help

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612169/pylint-not-recognizing-cv2-members)