# Pylint not recognizing opencv sub-modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

When installing `opencv-contrib-python` pylint does not recognize the **submodules** of the main `cv2` module (related but not identical: [PyLint not recognizing cv2 members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612169/pylint-not-recognizing-cv2-members)).

For instance, consider:

```
from cv2 import aruco
print(aruco.DICT_4X4_100)
```

Running pylint with `--extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2,cv2.aruco` gives the following message:

```
[pylint] Instance of 'module' has no 'DICT_4X4_100' member [E1101]
```

However, the code is perfectly valid and runs correctly and even
Python for VSCode is able to offer autocomplete for the `aruco` sub-module members. Also - since `cv2` is on the whitelist, pylint **does** recognize direct members of the `cv2` module (e.g. `cv2.imshow` etc.)

Can Pylint be configured to recognize the native sub-modules somehow?

Answer (score 0):

in `~/.pylintrc`, add `cv2.*` after

```
generated-members=
```

which became

```
generated-members=cv2.*
```

then the errors should be disappeared