# Visual Studio Code doesn't recognize cv2 members

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I don't know if this is on topic but I have seen some similar questions on this site.

The problem is simple, recently I have found out that Visual Studio Code cannot access any members of `cv2` at all. The attribute names are all white, hovering over them show "(function) {name}: Any", it doesn't autocomplete.

There is no red wave signalling that `cv2` import resolve failure. Hovering over cv2 show: "OpenCV Python binary extension loader".

Screenshot:

[image]

The code is working correctly and this question isn't about the code.

I have tried:

`from cv2 import cv2`, the second `cv2` is white.

Add `python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"]` to `settings.json`, the texts are darker, hovering over it shows: "Unknown Configuration Setting".

Tried `Python: Select Linter` in command palette: no such option was found.

I have installed many VS Code extensions. I have already selected the interpreter version to be same as the main interpreter which has all the external libraries installed.

How to fix this bug?

---

Previously Pylint wasn't listed as a standalone extension, but I have installed many Python extension packs that no doubt have included it. I have run `pylint --generate-rcfile > ./.pylintrc` in the directory where my scripts are kept, and installed Pylint as a standalone extension, and restarted the editor. The problem persists.

---

This bug is truly resilient, I have just resorted to drastic measures.

I have just uninstalled Visual Studio Code entirely via "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\unins000.exe", then I have deleted everything inside C:\Users\Xeni.vscode where the extensions are kept, effectively uninstalling all extensions. I have also deleted everything inside C:\Users\Xeni\AppData\Roaming\Code\ except for C:\Users\Xeni\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\History folder and C:\Users\Xeni\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\Settings.json.

Having done a complete reset, removing all possible files that could have caused the bug. I then downloaded the latest Visual Studio Code installer and installed it.

And then I have just installed 3 extensions: Black Formatter v2023.6.0 from Microsoft, Python v2023.22.1 from Microsoft, Sourcery v1.15.0, Pylance v2023.12.1 seems to be preinstalled.

Anyway these four extensions are the only ones in the current installation, but after setting things up and reloading Visual Studio Code, I opened the same file, and the same bug is still there...

Total file removal and reinstallation didn't fix the problem. And I can't think of another solution.

Comment: Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612169/pylint-not-recognizing-cv2-members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, all solutions I found online don't work.

Changing `settings.json` didn't work, switching linter didn't work, there wasn't such an option. Even completely uninstalling Visual Studio Code and removing all the files except settings and user history, and then reinstall VS Code and the extensions failed to solve the problem.

So I eliminated the impossible causes. This means other things must be the cause.

I have of course installed OpenCV, and my code works correctly in the console, and this interpreter is the same one used by Visual Studio Code.

**I just tried to update the cv2 version via `pip3.10 install opencv-python --upgrade`, this uninstalled opencv-python-4.7.0.72 and installed opencv-python-4.9.0.80. I then reloaded Visual Studio Code.**

And this worked. This fixed the problem, hovering over function names showed their arguments and return type, and there is also autocomplete.

I have no idea why this worked. I will leave this answer to anyone who faced the same problem.

Comment: Hi Ξένη Γήινος, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: installed same version, doesn't work on my windows